# Save image to gallery in xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin. I want to build a xamarin forms application to take picture and save it in the gallery. I built the app to take photo and display it by using the following article.

https://xamarinhelp.com/use-camera-take-photo-xamarin-forms/

But I don't know how to save the image in the gallery in xamarin forms.Can anyone help me to save the image using dependency service in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you shared uses `MediaPlugin` by jamesmontemagno. It has its own comprehensive [getting-started docs](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/README.md), that I would recommend to go through.

In order to save picture to gallery, you can use [`SaveToAlbum`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/README.md#saving-photovideo-to-camera-rollgallery) in `StoreCameraMediaOptions`.

```
var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
      new StoreCameraMediaOptions 
      { 
          SaveToAlbum = true 
      });
```

Comment: How to save an image to gallery which is in the in the display or in the drawable folder?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. But I would imagine you should be able to get an input stream for that resource and then use `File` or similar option to save it to storage.